# How to decompress a warc.zst file?

Tags: archive, webarchive, warc, zstd

I am trying to decompress a WARC ZST file that I downloaded from here: https://archive.org/details/archiveteam_yahooanswers_20210422220546_c4fac540

I tried the command `zstd -d yahooanswers_20210422220546_c4fac540.1619026173.megawarc.warc.zst` but I got this error:
`73.megawarc.warc.zst : 0 MB...     73.megawarc.warc.zst : Decoding error (36) : Dictionary mismatch` 
How can I find the said dictionary or are there any alternatives to this?

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary can be found inside the first skippable frame of the warc.

To extract the dictionary OrIdow6 write this to extract it: https://transfer.notkiska.pw/inline/TXlRo/xtract.py

You'll require python3, zstd and zstandard

`python ./xtract.py /path/to/megawarc.warc.zst > dict`

Then you can

`zstd -d /path/to/megawarc.warc.zst -D dict`

And you should be able to view the megawarc with your standard warc viewing tools

Comment: I am almost certain that this only works with Linux and not Windows. File "xtract.py" seems especially Linux-focused.

Comment: Which version of the  zstd and zstandard that this script is using?
I got this error after run: Traceback (most recent call last):  File "xtract.py", line 8, in <module>    from _zstd_cffi import ffi, lib ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_zstd_cffi'

Comment: On Windows, try using something like msys2 msys or msys2 ucrt64, and make sure the corresponding versions of these two packages are installed first:

**ucrt64/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-python-zstandard**
    *Python bindings to the Zstandard (zstd) compression library (mingw-w64)*
 and 
**ucrt64/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zstd** (replace ucrt64 with mingw64, mingw32 etc. depending on the version you chose.)